# How to deal with iteracy in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, sequence, iterable

I have this code:

```
def PCP(seq, feature):
  l = []
  mean = st.mean(list(feature.values()))
  std = np.std(list(feature.values()))
  for elem in seq:
      for aa in elem:
          if aa in feature:
              l.append((feature[aa]-mean)/std)
          else:
              l.append(0)
  return l
```

`seq` is a list of strings with sequences, and `feature` is a dict with aminoacids as keys and certain values as values. I want the function to get throught every `aa` in a string in the list (`seq`) and take the values that corresponds in the dict and make calculation.

Here is a piece of of data I put as `seq`, and `feature` dict:

`['KISKDLSIAVQMMKRIHSLLERYPEIL', 'SGRVEKSPHEQEIKFFAKILLPLINQY', 'IDQLIVFGEQLIQKSEPLDAVLIEDEL', ..], pI= {"K":9.47, "P":6.3, "R":10.76, "T":5.6, "A":6.11, "C":5.02, "D":2.98, "E":3.08, "F":5.91, "G":6.06, "H":7.64......}`

Maybe there is something wrong with them.

When I run the function I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-89a7be7ecda7> in <module>
----> 1 test_hydrofobowosc= PCP(test_data_neg, hydrofobowosc)

<ipython-input-12-2f318f9cb908> in PCP(seq, feature)
     14   mean = st.mean(list(feature.values()))
     15   std = np.std(list(feature.values()))
---> 16   for elem in seq:
     17       for aa in elem:
     18           if aa in feature:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is "iteracy"?

Comment: add the full _error traceback_

Comment: the indentation is suspicious, could you check it? In particular the `return` (as it is the function will perform a single iteration and exit)

Comment: The error message tells you that `seq` is `None`. It is **not** the list you think it is. You need to examine the code where you call the `PCP` function. Apparently `test_data_neg` is `None`, which is passed into `PCP` as `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

'range' returns a list of numbers.

therefore 'elem' is a number.

therefore it is not iterable.

do you mean 'for elem in seq' ?

Comment: don't use an answer to write a comment

Comment: this was my first thought, then I saw somewere o change it for range.
 anyway if I put 'for elem in seq' still got 'nonetype object' is no iterable

Comment: It's an answer to why he's getting 'iteracy' problems - he's trying to iterate a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your code that should work:

```
def PCP(seq, feature):
  l = []
  mean = st.mean(list(feature.values()))
  std = np.std(list(feature.values()))
  for elem in seq:
      for aa in elem:
          if aa in feature:
              l.append((feature[aa]-mean)/std)
          else:
              l.append(0)
  return l
```

The main changes I made were:

- Instead of using "range(len(seq))" to iterate through the list of sequences, I used "seq" directly. This way, "elem" will be the actual string in the list, instead of the index of the string.
- Inside the nested loop, I used "aa" as the variable to iterate through the characters in the string.
- When checking if the current character is "in" the feature dictionary, I used the in keyword instead of "keys[s]". This is because "keys()" is a method that returns a list-like object of the dictionary's keys, and you need to use "[]" to access an item in the list. Since "aa" is a string and not an index, you can just check if it's in the dictionary directly.
- I moved the "return l" statement outside of the nested loop, so that it only happens once after all the calculations are done.

With these changes, the code should work as expected and append the calculated values to the l list for each amino acid in the sequences that has a corresponding value in the feature dictionary.

Comment: I run your code and still got 'NoneType' object is not iterable for the -> for elem in seq. 
Could you look at the fragments of data I put as seq, and my features dict: ['KISKDLSIAVQMMKRIHSLLERYPEIL',
 'SGRVEKSPHEQEIKFFAKILLPLINQY',
 'IDQLIVFGEQLIQKSEPLDAVLIEDEL',
..]
pI= {"K":9.47, "P":6.3, "R":10.76, "T":5.6, "A":6.11, "C":5.02, "D":2.98, "E":3.08, "F":5.91, "G":6.06, "H":7.64......} maybe is smth wrong with them